# How do I print a float as an integer?

Tags: python, number-formatting

This is for a homework assignment in my Python class that I am having an issue on. I am not allowed to import anything or use try-except.

I want to take 3 numbers and print the smallest one without using the `min()` function. The issue I am having is that if the number is something like 5 it gets printed as `5.000000` because I converted all the numbers to floats. I tried using `rstrip('0')` and it prints it as `5.` which makes sense, but I need integers to be printed as an integer and floats to be printed as a float. Is there a simpler way to do this that I am missing?

My code for reference:

```
def min3(num1, num2, num3):
if (num1 <= num2):
    if(num1 <= num3):
        return num1
    else:
        return num3

if (num2 <= num1):
    if(num2 <= num3):
        return num2
    else:
        return num3

def main():
    num1 = float(input("Please enter the first number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Please enter the second number: "))
    num3 = float(input("Please enter the third number: "))

    smallest_num = min3(num1, num2, num3)
    print("The smallest number is %f." %(smallest_num))

main()
```

Comment: Why do you do `float(input(...))` if you really want `int(input(...))`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that the numbers the user enters can be either integers or decimals.

Comment: Why not just `print("The smallest number is", smallest_num)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
if smallest_num.is_integer():
   # print as integer
   print "The smallest is %d" % smallest_num
else:
   # print as float
   print "The smallest is %f" % smallest_num
```

Comment: @Erica actually '%s' is for strings (or any other objects that can be converted to string), '%f' for floats and '%d' for integers. See [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)